# Have Mercurial repo reject any push that would result in a multiheaded branch

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-hook, mercurial-commit

How can I configure a Mercurial repo to reject any push that would result in a multiheaded branch?

As a follow up, how can I configure a clone to always pull before a commit, so hg can warn if the commit will result in a multiheaded branch, so the user can either abort or know that they must merge / rebase after the commit?

Comment: For enforcing single head locally or on a server, set `experimental.single-head-per-branch = True` in your hgrc. In your case, you need to set it on server.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I’m using bitbucket.com, and I don’t think I can manually edit the `.hg/hgrc` there. Do you know a way to do this on bitbucket?

Comment: Why don't you add the bitbucket constraint explicitly to your question (and tag it as such)

Comment: @XDR sorry, I don't know of a way you can enable this on bitbucket. You can also enable this locally everywhere so that you don't create multihead branch locally and hence preventing from pushing one.